# How to find the nodes that overlap between two sets of nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a directed graph, and for a given node N, I want to find the nodes who have inbound relationships to N but not outbound relationships from N.  It seems like it should be a simple thing, but I'm having trouble getting my head wrapped around the query.

so I've got:
    start n=node({id}) match (n)<-[:RELTYPE]-inbound

but can't figure out how to structure the rest of the clause.  I'm feeling rather stupid.  I could, of course, just do two queries and perform the calculation in my Java code, but it seems like there should be a query that would do the job more efficiently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, I"m an idiot.

start n=node({id}) match n<-[:RELTYPE]-someone where not n-[:RELTYPE]->someone return someone;